# WPF: populate different enum into my ComBoBox base on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

So I have 2 `enums:

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
        public enum A400TypeOption
        {
            [Description("Temperature")]
            TEMPERATURE = 0,
    
            [Description("Humidity sensor")]
            HUMIDITY = 2,
        }

[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
        public enum A700TypeOption
        {
            [Description("Temperature")]
            TEMPERATURE = 1,
    
            [Description("High")]
            HIGH = 2,

            [Description("Voltage")]
            VOLTAGE = 3,
        }
```

I have this `EnumBindingSource` class:

```
public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
        private Type _enumType;

        public Type EnumType
        {
            get { return this._enumType; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this._enumType)
                {
                    if (null != value)
                    {
                        Type enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value) ?? value;
                        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
                            throw new ArgumentException("Type must be for an Enum.");
                    }

                    this._enumType = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public EnumBindingSourceExtension() { }

        public EnumBindingSourceExtension(Type enumType)
        {
            this.EnumType = enumType;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (null == this._enumType)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The EnumType must be specified.");

            Type actualEnumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(this._enumType) ?? this._enumType;
            Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(actualEnumType);

            if (actualEnumType == this._enumType)
                return enumValues;

            Array tempArray = Array.CreateInstance(actualEnumType, enumValues.Length + 1);
            enumValues.CopyTo(tempArray, 1);
            return tempArray;
        }
}
```

And this is my `ComBoBox` that get its `enum`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type tagEnums:A400TypeOption}}}"   
</ComboBox>
```

As you can see, and this example, my `ComBoBox` populate with the `enum` `A400TypeOption`.

Now I have another `ComBoBox` that the user can choose between `A400` and `A700` and base on this selection I want to populate my `ComBoBox` with the relevant `enum` (`A400TypeOption` or `A700TypeOption`).
So I created this `int value` property in my `ViewModel`:

```
private int enumType;

public int EnumType
{
    get { return enumType; }
    set
    {
        enumType = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("EnumType");
    }
}
```

And in case the user select `A400` and the `EnumType` value is `0` I want to populate my `ComBoBox` this way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type tagEnums:A400TypeOption}}}"
```

And in case the user select `A700` and the `EnumType` value is `1` I want to populate my `ComBoBox` this way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type tagEnums:A700TypeOption}}}"
```

So I wonder how can I do that ?
I think maybe create `converter` and honesty I don't know what to pass to this `converter`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why don't have 2 combobox and hide the one that your are not using?

Comment: I don't really understand why you are going to this length to avoid an ObservableCollection<Enum> property in your ViewModel and when your int property changes you refill the collection and NotifyPropertyChanged? Then you can pass actual instances of the enum to your converter and get the type by reflection or pass it as a parameter

Comment: The sooner you start using MVVM, the better (easier) your WPF experience will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SelectType">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A400" Tag="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type tagEnums:A400TypeOption}}}" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A700" Tag="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type tagEnums:A700TypeOption}}}" />
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=SelectType}" />
```